# File type mismatch: No overload matches this call

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to pass a file to Papaparse.

```
import Papa from 'papaparse'
import type { ParseResult } from 'papaparse'

const csv = ref<ParseResult<any>>()
const file = ref<File>()

function onFileChanged($event: Event) {
  const target = $event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (target && target.files) {
    file.value = target.files[0];
  }
}

function submitFile() {
  if (!file.value) {
    console.log("no file")
  }

  Papa.parse(file.value, { // Red underline here: No overload matches this call.
    complete: onParseCsv,
  })
}

function onParseCsv(results: ParseResult<any>) {
  console.log(results)
}
```

The code works, and I do get results, but I don't understand why there's an error saying that I'm using the wrong type.

The full error is:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(76, 17): The last overload is declared here.
```

The function I'm calling has the following type:

```
export function parse<T, TFile extends LocalFile = LocalFile>(file: TFile, config: ParseLocalConfig<T, TFile>): void;

export type LocalFile = Blob | NodeJS.ReadableStream;
```

Can someone explain what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: There should be a lot more text in the error message. Can you post all of it? It should include a description of what overloads do exist, and why none matched. From there we can compare the expected and actual types, to hopefully determine the issue.

Comment: I updated with more info, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `file.value` can be `undefined`, which is not allowed. The error is a little cryptic because `Papa.parse` is overloaded, so it just mentions the last overload, which expects a `unique symbol`.

If you add an `else` branch the code type checks:

```
function submitFile() {
  if (!file.value) {
    console.log("no file")
  } else {
    Papa.parse(file.value, {
      complete: onParseCsv,
    })
  }
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgMzgXzmqERwBEAbgK4qEDcAUKJLHAAoCGYzOeBA5G781AGcUXWuGjwYATzApETfkIBKKAaQA28bLnxwerfYOHVqAYwgA7AfBMDicALzJ0AHhaHlqjc%20bnJAPj8ACgBKUwsrHGA1WUdUNGcAMSiUINDqNFJzExhgCzgLJOiAYQALHwBzFAATQIASFGIUcxgALjgAUUbm4MRqODgzSwl%20SvhHeq6YADoYEZR4ZgE4AAkAFQBZABkASXMwUhh26JAmmBp%204AxA2ahRuAAye7gb0am0ZIEehD7%20yOip4jMNTkBzPObTd7RAQAbQADABdc5YaiYYwZLI5PKqABGIGAMEKKBCvQuVwAhJCUACgeQvj9%20oMBBB-moIOVAoRzBA-hRQv1sCg1EISb8WGwpmxDIFKdTgSgADQi34DfBgaIwFBtCxuIRFWzy%20lYPnI1HpTLZXLmfLmHUoPXEQKoTwwARtW0edQwby%20Px0hnhZlU1nsp2ez4ooA)

Comment: Thanks! I added an early return and that fixed the issue. TIL all types in TS are nullable by default.